# How to set state for individual state variable in react + typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

when I click button, "isLoading" set to true and loading gif seems in page, process simple here its click function;

```
private clickFunction(e): void {
    this.state.isLoading=true; ..
```

so i expect this loading gif seems in page;

```
<div style={{"display":this.state.isLoading?"block":"none"}}><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
```

but its not working.. whats wrong here? since if initial value of isLoading   property set as true, gif seems on plageload so whats I think state not updating the render or ?

**EDITED** :
When I try to update only one property of state ts compiler throws this exception;
[image]
Whats worng with here ?

```
export interface IWebPartState {
  status: string;
  Name: string;
  isLoading:boolean;
}
export default class Contact extends React.Component<IContactProperties, IWebPartState> { ...
```

Comment: `this.state.isLoading=true` is wrong. instead use `setState`

Comment: @jose920405 where if there is many properties? do I have to set others also ? how can I edit individual property of state?

Comment: Are you using reactjs with typescript?

Comment: @HardikModha yes ts 2.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting state in a wrong way,
Instead of doing `this.state.isLoading=true`, you should set state using `setState` as follows,

```
this.setState({
    isLoading: true
});
```

Read more about state [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state) and setState [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

**Edit:** As you are using reactjs with typescript, You will need to make property optional in the type interface and you can do that using `?`. Read more about it in optional properties section [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
interface IGifLoadingState {
    isLoading?: boolean;
    status?: string;
}
```

After declaring properties optional, typescript will allow you to set any individual property in the state.

Comment: but i have many properties in state, and i think seting single property of state is not possible, is it?

Comment: @TyForHelpDude `setState` will only update the properties you pass to it.

Comment: Yes, You can pass individual property, that you want to set.

Comment: @TyForHelpDude [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ZeTruC6Qs52OTO4j1cB?p=preview) I've created a little example for you. You'll need to open browser console to see the results.

Comment: @HardikModha ty for answer and example actually you done the part of the origin of the post but still confusing about setting single property of state. can you check you post

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Hi @HardikModha, what about if I want to update the old value of the old state variable? Like: this.state.count = this.state.count +7 ?

Comment: @Andiana You should use the different variant of `setState` which accepts a function as the first argument. `this.setState((prevState) => { return {count: prevState.count + 1}; });`. You can read more about it in the [Official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have changed since...

If you look at React type definitions (index.d.t, React 16), you see that setState method signature in Typescript is :

```
class Component<P, S> {
...
  setState<K extends keyof S>(state: Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;
...
}
```

`S`is our component state, in your case it's `IWebPartState`

Look at [this SO question to understand what it means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616585/why-does-the-new-pickt-k-extends-keyof-t-type-allow-subsets-of-k-in-react), but to make it short: you don't have to make your interface properties optional, yet you can pass only a subset of them to `setState`