# Why does the new `Pick<T, K extends keyof T>` type allow subsets of `K` in React's `setState()`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.1

I thought I understood the purpose of the new [TS 2.1 `Pick` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick), but then I saw [how it was being used in the React type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/index.d.ts#L171) and I don't understand:

```
declare class Component<S> {
    setState<K extends keyof S>(state: Pick<S, K>, callback?: () => any): void;
    state: Readonly<S>;
}
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
interface PersonProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class Person extends Component<{}, PersonProps> {
  test() {
    this.setState({ age: 123 });
  }
}
```

My confusion here is that `keyof S` is `{ name, age }` but I call `setState()` with only `age` -- why doesn't it complain about the missing `name`?

My first thought is that because `Pick` is an index type, it simply doesn't require all the keys to exist. Makes sense. But if I try to assign the type directly:

```
const ageState: Pick<PersonProps, keyof PersonProps> = { age: 123 };
```

It *does* complain about the missing `name` key:

```
Type '{ age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<PersonProps, "name" | "age">'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{ age: number; }'.
```

I don't understand this. It *seems* all I did was fill in `S` with the type that `S` is already assigned to, and it went from allowing a *sub-set* of keys to requiring *all* keys. This is a big difference. [Here it is in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20class%20Component%3CP%2C%20S%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setState%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20S%3E(state%3A%20Pick%3CS%2C%20K%3E%2C%20callback%3F%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20any)%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20Readonly%3CS%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20PersonProps%20%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Person%20extends%20Component%3C%7B%7D%2C%20PersonProps%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20test()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20person%3A%20Pick%3CPersonProps%2C%20keyof%20PersonProps%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20age%3A%20123%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7B%20age%3A%20123%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D). Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer:** if you really want an explicit type, you can use `Pick<PersonProps, "age">`, but it's easier use implicit types instead.

**Long answer:**

The key point is that the `K` is a generic type variable which *extends* `keyof T`.

The type `keyof PersonProps` is equal to the string union `"name" | "age"`. The type `"age"` can be said to extend the type `"name" | "age"`.

Recall the definition of `Pick` is:

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]: T[P];
}
```

which means for every `K`, the object described by this type must have a property `P` of same type as the property `K` in `T`. Your example playground code was:

```
const person: Pick<PersonProps, keyof PersonProps> = { age: 123 };
```

Unwrapping the generic type variables, we get:

- `Pick<T, K extends keyof T>`,
- `Pick<PersonProps, "name" | "age">`,
- `[P in "name" | "age"]: PersonProps[P]`, and finally
- `{name: string, age: number}`.

This is, of course, incompatible with `{ age: 123 }`. If you instead say:

```
const person: Pick<PersonProps, "age"> = { age: 123 };
```

then, following the same logic, the type of `person` will properly be equivalent to `{age: number}`.

Of course, TypeScript is calculating all of these types for you anyway—that's how you got the error. Since TypeScript already knows the types `{age: number}` and `Pick<PersonProps, "age">` are compatible, you might as well keep the type impicit:

```
const person = { age: 123 };
```

Comment: *The type `"age"` can be said to extend the type `"name" | "age"`.*
Ah, I wouldn't have guessed that, I would think that `"name" | "age"` extends `"age"`, not the other way. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Sorry to bump this again, but while I understand the behavior now (thanks!), I can't really rationalize how `"age"` is a super-type of `"age" | "name"` and not a sub-type, even though its clearly how the compiler sees it. It seems top be the inverse of how the seemingly equivalent interfaces `{name, age}` and `{age}` relate to each other. Can you explain this rationale?

Comment: In a generic type constraint, perhaps it's best to read "extends" as "is a more specific type of." Consider `type AB = "a" | "b";` and `type ABC = "a" | "b" | "c";`. If you have a variable `const abc: ABC = "c";` then you could not assign that to a variable of type `AB`, but any valid value of type `AB` is a valid value of `ABC`. As `AB` is a more specific type of `ABC`, `AB` can be said to *extend* `ABC`.

Comment: (Oops my last comment I used super-type/sub-type backwards.) Thanks for the explanation, I can see that meaning. I guess `extends` has unfamiliar meaning for union types for me, but I think it makes a bit more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how it is possible that React can use partial state in a parameter without declaring the properties in the state parameter as optional?